# Identity type must be integral (int, long, uint, ulong)' when trying to map using NFluentHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nfluent

I'm trying to map an object using NFluentHibernate mapping. Id of that object is type of Guid.
Because of that, I am getting this error

> Identity type must be integral (int, long, uint, ulong)'

Mapping :

```
  Schema("`Base.Pricing`");
  Table("DocumentDetails");

  Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity(); //LINE THAT CAUSES THE ERROR

  Map(x => x.Name).Nullable();
  Map(x => x.Status).Nullable();
  Map(x => x.PublicAccessUrl).Nullable();

  HasOne(x => x.Pricing)
   .Cascade.All();
```

EntityObject

```
public class DocumentDetails: EntityBase<DocumentDetails>
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string PublicAccessUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual int PricingId { get; set; }

    public virtual Pricing Pricing { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
```

by this

```
Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.GuidNative();
```